# corrupt record while reading xml file using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to read an xml file in dataframe in pyspark.

Code :
`df_xml=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rootTag","dataset").option("rowTag","AUTHOR").load(FilePath)`

when i display the dataframe, it shows a single column corrupt_records :

[image]

below is the xml file content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<dataset>
 
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = 1>
    <FIRST_NAME>Fiona</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME/>
    <LAST_NAME>Macdonald</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = 2>
    <FIRST_NAME>Gian</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME>Paolo</MIDDLE_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Faleschini</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = 3>
    <FIRST_NAME>Laura</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME>K</MIDDLE_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Egendorf</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = 4>
    <FIRST_NAME>Jan</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME/>
    <LAST_NAME>Grover</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That XML is not valid:

- The AUTHOR_UID must be defined in quotes
- The dataset tag is not closed

This example below is a valid one:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<dataset>
 
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = '1'>
    <FIRST_NAME>Fiona</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME/>
    <LAST_NAME>Macdonald</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = '2'>
    <FIRST_NAME>Gian</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME>Paolo</MIDDLE_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Faleschini</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = '3'>
    <FIRST_NAME>Laura</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME>K</MIDDLE_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Egendorf</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 <AUTHOR AUTHOR_UID = '4'>
    <FIRST_NAME>Jan</FIRST_NAME>
    <MIDDLE_NAME/>
    <LAST_NAME>Grover</LAST_NAME>
 </AUTHOR>
 
 </dataset>
```

Comment: thanks Luiz, it seems Author_ID value not being in the quote was causing the problem. Dataset tag was closed in the file, though i only shared a few records, so it was missing in the example.